# how to remove a list item of ListView from onitemclick listener

Tags: android, listview

i know how to remove a list item by using list adapter.But i want to remove a list item from a actvity which showing the list view.i am using onitemClick Listener for getting data from list item.after getting data i need to remove that item from  a list view.how to do that?

Comment: Please read the [hint for asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and show us a minimal code example to reproduce the problem.

Comment: remove from arraylist by position

Comment: onitemClick Listener get position and remove from arraylist

Comment: what is the datsource you used to populate listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to this code..

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);

TestAdapter adpter = new TestAdapter(Test.this, arralist);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()

{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick (AdapterView < ? > adapterView, View view,int position, long l){
    arralist.remove(position);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}

);
```

Comment: how do i get adapter instance? to call NotifydataChanged() method.

Comment: @ Rajesh.k please check this i have edited how to instance adapter..and if this answer help you, then accept this answer..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While not best practice you can also call the change on the adapter.

```
 view.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(position));
            }
        });
```

Comment: how do i get adapter instance? so that i can use adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(position));

Comment: Hey Rajesh.k, you obviously would have to instantiate your adapter either as a local final as shown by Dileep, or a field variable in your class.